# Sticky footer starts off the screen

Tags: jquery

I've got a sticky footer that's currently off the screen:

```
<div id="footer"> <!-- Your footer here --> </div>


 $(window).bind("load", function () {
    var footer = $("#footer");
    var pos = footer.position();
    var height = $(window).height();
    height = height - pos.top;
    height = height - footer.height();
    if (height > 0) {
        footer.css({
            'margin-top': height + 'px'
        });
    }
});
```

At the moment the footer starts after the viewport, so you have to scroll down to see it. How can I pull it up slightly so it sits within the viewport?

Comment: Are you interested in a [pure css solution](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `footer.height();` into `footer.innerHeight();`.

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/richardmauritz/pen/zwqqMr)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `footer.height()` with [`footer.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/). Then use [`$(document).ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) instead of `$(window).bind` since `.bind` is now deprecated.

https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aj08qffx/